# I want to compare two config files, but the processing changes the layout of the file slightly

Tags: python, compare, md5

I have a program which runs a series of tests on a device. The device imports a config file at the start of the script, and the end result is to check that the config is the same and was successfully imported.

However, once the device gets the config, it restructures the config slightly. This may have something to do with spacing/tabs. For example:

```
<         option ifname 'eth0'
<         option proto 'static'
<         option ipaddr '192.168.100.1'
<         option netmask '255.255.255.0'
```

on the original config file, when exported again changes to:

```
>       option ifname 'eth0'
>       option proto 'static'
>       option ipaddr '192.168.100.1'
>       option netmask '255.255.255.0'
```

Ideally, I was going to do an md5sum check on these two files. Does anybody know another way?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have to do it in Python, you can just use `diff --ignore-space-change` to compare the files.

If you really want to do it in Python, you could strip all leading white space from the original and final files (`str.lstrip()`), and compare the md5sum of the results.  Unless the md5sum is useful for something, you could just do a comparison of the files line-by-line in a Python `for` loop.